# Auto-correct case spelling of a word database

Tags: python

I am stuck on a seemingly simple Python problem since 2 days.
It involves updating a 'database' of mixed string/tuple sequences (with always the same structure) but with case-sensitive mistake correction.

For instance the database is:

```
[['Abc',  ('Def',  'Ghi'),  'Jkl'],
 ['Abc',  ('Def',  'Mno'),  'Pqr'],
 ['123',  ('456',  '789'),  '012'],
 ['ToTo', ('TiTi', 'TaTa'), 'TeTe']]
```

Now if I input another sequence with same words but different case, I would like it to be corrected automatically:

```
['abc',  ('def',  'ghi'),  'jkl']  ->  ['Abc', ('Def',  'Ghi'),  'Jkl']
['abc',  ('def',  'XYZ'),  'jkl']  ->  ['Abc', ('Def',  'XYZ'),  'jkl']
['abc',  ('titi', 'tata'), 'tete'] ->  ['Abc', ('titi', 'tata'), 'tete']
```

So the items should be corrected as long as we don't meet a different word.

The real problem is that each item can be a string or a tuple, otherwise it won't be so difficult.
I've tried using a 'flatten' function and check items per items, and then rebuild the original structure but the processing is too heavy (database can grow to more 50 000 sequences).

Do someone know some magic trick in Python which would help my current problem ?

Thanks a lot !

Comment: Why not `TiTi`, `TaTa` and `TeTe`? And why is the `jkl` in your second line unchanged?

Comment: Because the order is important, we are allowed to correct as long we don't find a different word. So we can correct the beginning but as soon as the word is different, we stop correcting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest using a dictionary to convert your words from some generic form (perhaps all lowercase) to the "correct" form that you want to have all items use in the database. Since the path to a word matters, I suggest using a tuple including all the previous normalized paths as the key into the dictionary:

```
_corrections = {}

def autocorrect(sequence):
    normalized = () # used as keys into _autocorrection_dict
    corrected = []  # values from _autocorrection_dict
    for item in sequence:
        if isinstance(item, str):
            normalized += (item.lower(),)
            corrected = _corrections.setdefault(normalized, corrected + [item])

        elif isinstance(item, tuple):
            sub_norm = tuple(subitem.lower() for subitem in item)
            if normalized + (sub_norm,) not in _corrections:
                sub_corrected = ()
                for subitem in item:
                    sub_result = _corrections.setdefault(normalized + (subitem.lower(),),
                                                         corrected + [subitem])
                    sub_corrected += (sub_result[-1],)
                _corrections[normalized + (sub_norm,)] = corrected + [sub_corrected]
            normalized += (sub_norm,)
            corrected = _corrections[normalized]

        else:
            raise TypeError("Unexpected item type: {}".format(type(item).__name__))

    return corrected
```

The first part of this code (the `if` block) handles simple string values. It should be fairly easy to understand. It builds up a tuple of "normalized" values, which is just the strings seen so far in all lowercase. The normalized tuple is used as a key into the `_corrections` dictionary, where we store the "correct" result. The magic happens in the `setdefault` call, which creates a new entry if one doesn't already exist.

The second part of the code (the `elif` block) is the much more complicated bit for dealing with tuple values. First we normalize all the strings in the tuple, and check if we already have a result for it (this lets us avoid the rest if we've already seen this exact tuple). If not, we have to check if there are previously saved results for each of the subitems in the tuple (so `["foo", ("BAR", "BAZ")]` will have `"BAR"` and `"BAZ"` corrected if there were already entries for `["foo", "bar"]` and `["foo", "baz"]`). Once we've found correct values for each of the subitems in the tuple, we can put them all together and then add the combined result to the dictionary. Making the short circuiting part work is a bit awkward, but I think it's worth it.

Here's an example session using the code:

```
>>> autocorrect(['Abc',  ('Def',  'Ghi'),  'Jkl'])
['Abc', ('Def', 'Ghi'), 'Jkl']
>>> autocorrect(['ABC', ("DEF", "GGGG"), "JKL"])
['Abc', ('Def', 'GGGG'), 'JKL']
>>> autocorrect(['abC', 'gggg', 'jkL'])
['Abc', 'GGGG', 'jkL']
```

`"Abc"` is always put into the same form, and `"Def"` and `"GGGG"` are too, when they are used. the different forms of `"Jkl"` however don't ever get modified, since they're each following a different earlier value.

While this is perhaps the best solution if your database can't be changed, a much easier approach would be to simply force all of your data into the same normalization scheme. You could probably write some fairly simple code to go through your existing data to make it all consistent, then just normalize each new item you get without there being any need to worry about what the previous entries were.

Comment: If the beginning of the sequence is not the same, then the ending of a sequence cannot be corrected (it is the rule I got). To give you an 'image', it is because words in this context are linked together so ['AAA', 'bbb'] is the same as ['aaa', 'bbb'] or ['aaa', 'BBB'] BUT is not the same as ['xxx', 'BBB'] (here we cannot for sure tell that 'BBB' is a case spelling mistake).

Comment: Ah, I think I understand. Do words in tuples with different partners need to be autocorrected if they're at the same level? That is, if we already have `["foo", ("bar", "baz")]` should `bar` be lowercased in `["foo", ("BAR", "quux")`, or would only a `("BAR", "BAZ")` tuple need to be fixed?

Comment: You got it, ['foo', ('BAR', 'quux')] should be corrected to ['foo', ('bar', 'quux')]

Comment: Well, crap. I was just about to post an update that fixed the algorithm without making partially-matching tuples have consistent capitalization. Are you sure that's needed? If so, are we assured that the tuples are always one level deep, rather than potentially being nested? That is to say, is `["foo", ("bar", ("baz", "quux"))]` a valid item? That would at least keep things from getting to out of hand.

Comment: Yes it is unfortunately needed. However the tuple are always only one level deep (thank god !). Thanks for taking the time to help me !

Comment: @SaintGermain OK, it's fixed, I think. It should handle make tuple-value items in such a way that they're consistent with other tuples with the same previous values, and with non-tuple values at that same level. While I was working on it though, I did think of an alternative solution, which I mention in the last paragraph of the answer.

Comment: Nice and elegant solution, all the magic happens thanks to the setdefault: I will remember this trick. Thank you very much !

Answer (score 1):

Try NLTK using Brown and PorterStemmer. Brown have a very wide word list and a pre-learned stemmer.

Example:

```
from nltk import PorterStemmer
from nltk.corpus import brown

import sys
from collections import defaultdict
import operator

def sortby(nlist ,n, reverse=0):
    nlist.sort(key=operator.itemgetter(n), reverse=reverse)

class mydict(dict):
    def __missing__(self, key):
        return 0

class DidYouMean:
    def __init__(self):
        self.stemmer = PorterStemmer()

    def specialhash(self, s):
        s = s.lower()
        s = s.replace("z", "s")
        s = s.replace("h", "")
        for i in [chr(ord("a") + i) for i in range(26)]:
            s = s.replace(i+i, i)
        s = self.stemmer.stem(s)
        return s

    def test(self, token):
        hashed = self.specialhash(token)
        if hashed in self.learned:
            words = self.learned[hashed].items()
            sortby(words, 1, reverse=1)
            if token in [i[0] for i in words]:
                return 'This word seems OK'
            else:
                if len(words) == 1:
                    return 'Did you mean "%s" ?' % words[0][0]
                else:
                    return 'Did you mean "%s" ? (or %s)' \
                           % (words[0][0], ", ".join(['"'+i[0]+'"' \
                                                      for i in words[1:]]))
        return "I can't found similar word in my learned db"

    def learn(self, listofsentences=[], n=2000):
        self.learned = defaultdict(mydict)
        if listofsentences == []:
            listofsentences = brown.sents()
        for i, sent in enumerate(listofsentences):
            if i >= n: # Limit to the first nth sentences of the corpus
                break
            for word in sent:
                self.learned[self.specialhash(word)][word.lower()] += 1

def demo():
    d = DidYouMean()
    d.learn()
    # choice of words to be relevant related to the brown corpus
    for i in "birdd, oklaoma, emphasise, bird, carot".split(", "):
        print i, "-", d.test(i)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    demo()
```

Install:
http://www.nltk.org/install.html

You will need the data as well to get this working:
http://www.nltk.org/data.html

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You should define a function like this:

```
def capitalize(structure):
    return [structure[0].capitalize(), (structure[1][0].capitalize(), structure[1][0].capitalize()), structure[2].capitalize()]
```

However this is a very ugly solution. You should probably think at another way to represent data in a more clever way.

Comment: The sequence can be any mix of string and tuple and of any length. However a database can only contain one type of sequence. I am trying to design a generic answer which is CPU efficient.

Comment: What is the difference between the elements contained in the tuple with respect to the standalone elements?

Comment: Tuple are just a list of strings (like the other elements), they cannot contain other things (like a tuple of tuple for instance).

Comment: Why do you need them in your application?

Comment: They are used as keys for a nested dictionary. For instance dictionary['Abc'][('Def','Ghi')]['Jkl']. However there were a lot of case spelling mistake so we want to correct this.